# Which sql server data type best represents a double in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, double

Is it money, float, real, decimal, _________ ?

Comment: That expanded part would be better as a new question.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Answer to this and all mapping of types can be found here.

[SQL-CLR Type Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx)

Chart, stolen from that page:

[image]

---

Updated 1/7/2013 - there's a more recent version, .not so colorful here: 
[SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKZCS.gif)

Comment: Thanks.  Nice typo by Microsoft in there - DECIMIAL

Comment: @pseudonym27 - That has to do with how well the operating system can be expected to translate SQL Server data types into .NET Runtime data types and vice-versa.  Any time you go between two different platforms there's a risk of data loss because the binary implementation of eachtype is not guaranteed to be the same.  Also, not all numeric data types are able to be accurately represented in binary, so the system stores only the approximate value.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net

Comment: This chart is pretty, but wrong - it lists ...Enum as if there's some way to generally convert those to DB types, but enums behave as their underlying integral type (i.e. most are int32's and roundtrip precisely with db ints); and it suggests that char(1) is equivalent to a .net char - when unicode clearly implies that it isn't.  Also, Date and DateTime *clearly* do not mutually roundtrip...  and when mapping a DB real to a .net decimal, you can get dataloss also when saving to the database...   I didn't check exhaustively, but this chart looks like garbage.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne, the chart says "without data loss exceptions", not "without data loss".  Does your comment still stand?

Answer (score 17):

That would be float.

See [Mapping CLR Parameter Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

Float is the sql type you are looking for.

Comment: You are right that is the best match.
Sadly Float is one of the worst datatypes you can use in SQL Server if you will need to perform math onthe field later as it creates rounding errors since it is not exact. As a dba I would not want people to define fields as float as I have had to deal with the mess they create when you want to do reporting on the data in the database and the calculations are incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

float matches best. real is only 32 bits in precision, so essentially useless.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx

Answer (score 1):

"The synonym for double precision is float(53)." Default value of n is 53.

From page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx