# What is the equivalent SQL Server type for the C# long type?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'd like to know what the equivalent SQL Server type is for a `long` in C#.

Comment: Answered here, along with the equivalent for other types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440620/which-sql-server-data-type-best-represents-a-double-in-c/1440631#1440631

Comment: right, thank you all... silly question ...

Comment: I don't see why this was worth a downvote.  it's a legitimate question.

Comment: yeh, I saw that thread but failed to see the simple fact that long is an int64 ... 
Anyways fair enough - its been asked and answered b4 ...

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The [mapping table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx) is clear - `BIGINT` is the equivalent of `Int64` (which is `long` in C#).

Answer (score 25):

The equivalent type is [`bigint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) which is a 64-bit numeric type.

It fits numbers in the range from `-2^63` to `2^63-1` which is the same as the [C# `long` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/long).