# Alter All Columns datatype in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

When I imported a table in SQL it suggested real datatype, now I would like to change all columns to **double type**...

Is there any script to automatically do this in SQL Managment Studio

My table is 500 columns:

```
`After doing` EXECUTE sp_help traS

Col Type  Comp len Prec Scale   Nullable TrimTrailing Fixed Collation
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
x1  real    no  4   24      NULL    yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
x2  real    no  4   24      NULL    yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
x3  real    no  4   24      NULL    yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
x4  real    no  4   24      NULL    yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
...
x500 real   no  4   24      NULL    yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
```

Comment: mmm, How would be the cursor, don't get it...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following code will place a list of columns into a temporary table called `@cols`, loop through that table, generate an `alter table alter column` statement, and execute it for each column.

If you need to exclude columns, you should include those in the `NOT IN` predicate of the select from information_schema.columns.

```
declare @cols table (i int identity, colname varchar(100))
insert into @cols
select column_name
from information_schema.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'yourtable'
and COLUMN_NAME not in ('exclude1', 'exclude2')

declare @i int, @maxi int
select @i = 1, @maxi = MAX(i) from @cols

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

while(@i <= @maxi)
begin
    select @sql = 'alter table yourtable alter column ' + colname + ' decimal(18,4) NULL'
    from @cols
    where i = @i

    exec sp_executesql @sql

    select @i = @i + 1
end
```

Comment: +1, but I recommend the op to first visit this link: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: Is it neccesary to have any privileges, When execute your code I get:`(500 row(s) affected)
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NULL'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NULL'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NULL'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NULL'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
.....
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NULL'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1`

Comment: Also I tried only one without being dynamic `alter table traS alter column x1 double null ` BUT an error shows: INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR NULL Expecting ID.

Comment: I updated the query, try again. Double isn't a valid data-type, you need to use decimal or numeric instead. The 2 numbers inside of the parentheses are the total number of digits (precision) and the number of digits that appear after the decimal (scale), respectively.

Comment: @Derek Kromm: one question, How can I set to double the datatype of columns (guess there is one option for doubles).... Is not the case decimal is not useful, but just want to set up double type

Comment: @cMinor, this isn't .NET or Java - there is no double type. Your options are numeric and decimal which, as far as I know, are equivalent. The maximum number is `10^33 - 1` I believe. If you need to hold larger numbers, then you need to use `float`. See here for more info on data types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Rough psuedocode would look like the following. It is untested however as I don't have a VM handy

```
-- Create a cursor that will iterate through
-- all the rows that meet the criteria DECLARE csr CURSOR FOR 
-- This query attempts to define the set of columns
-- that are reals  
SELECT 
    SC.name AS column_name  
FROM
    sys.tables ST 
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.columns SC
        ON SC.object_id = ST.object_id
    INNER JOIN
        sys.types T
        -- these column names are close but not right
        ON T.type_id = SC.system_type_id 
WHERE
    -- make this your table name
    ST.name = 'traS'
    -- look at actual values in sys.types
    AND T.name = 'real'

DECLARE 
    -- this holds the current column name
    @column_name sysname 
,   @base_query varchar(max) 
,   @actual_query varchar(max)

-- template query for fixing what's buggered
SET @base_query = 'ALTER TABLE traS ALTER COLUMN [<X/>] decimal(18,2) NULL'

FETCH NEXT FROM csr 
INTO @column_name  
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1) BEGIN
    IF (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -2)
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            SET @actual_query = REPLACE(@base_query, '<X/>', @column_name)
            EXECUTE (@actual_query)
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            PRINT 'Failed executing statement '
            PRINT @actual_query
        END CATCH
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM csr 
    INTO @colum_name 
END 
CLOSE csr 
DEALLOCATE csr
```

Orange bar overhead says I'm too slow but I'll submit anyways as I spent far too much time typing ;)

Comment: One question How do you get `C.name`?

Comment: Should have been SC as the sys.column table will hold the name for the column. Query fixed for that one

Comment: also, might want to read this thread and figure out what data type your app needs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209181/what-represents-a-double-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to bilinkc!

That was the solution for me.

I made it work on MSSQL 2019 and added the is_nullable flag.

So with this script you can **alter all columns** in the named **table** and change the **datatype** including **nullable** and **not nullable** fields correctly.

```
declare @TableName varchar(255) = 'TableName';
declare @DataTypeOld varchar(max) = 'float';
declare @DataTypeNew varchar(max) = 'decimal (19,4)';

DECLARE csrTemp CURSOR FOR
SELECT 
    SC.name AS column_name, SC.is_nullable
FROM
    sys.tables ST 
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.columns SC
        ON SC.object_id = ST.object_id
    INNER JOIN
        sys.types T
        ON T.system_type_id = SC.system_type_id
WHERE
    ST.name = @TableName
    AND T.name = @DataTypeOld
OPEN csrTemp;

DECLARE 
    -- this holds the current column name
    @column_name sysname,
    @is_nullable bit,
    @base_query varchar(max),
    @actual_query varchar(max);

-- template query for changing the datatype
SET @base_query = 'ALTER TABLE '+@TableName+' ALTER COLUMN [<X/>] '+ @DataTypeNew;

declare @Count int = 0;
FETCH NEXT FROM csrTemp 
INTO @column_name, @is_nullable;
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1) BEGIN
    IF (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -2)
    BEGIN
        SET @Count = @Count +1;
        BEGIN TRY
            SET @actual_query = REPLACE(@base_query, '<X/>', @column_name);
            IF @is_nullable = 1
                SET @actual_query = @actual_query + ' NULL';
            ELSE
                SET @actual_query = @actual_query + ' NOT NULL';
            EXECUTE (@actual_query);
            PRINT @actual_query;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SET @Count = @Count -1;
            PRINT '---------------------------';
            PRINT 'Failed executing statement: '+@actual_query;
            PRINT 'ERROR: '+ ERROR_MESSAGE();
            PRINT '';
        END CATCH
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM csrTemp
    INTO @column_name, @is_nullable;
END 
CLOSE csrTemp;
DEALLOCATE csrTemp;
PRINT '---------------------------';
print 'Altered '+ cast(@Count as varchar) + ' columns.';
```