# SQL Server Express - Incorrect Syntax near ','

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am getting an anoying error on this simple sql and I can't spot the error, any help will be appretiated.

```
CREATE TABLE alertitem 
    ([id] INT, 
     [dateposted] DATETIME, 
     [daterevised] DATETIME, 
     [datestart] DATETIME, 
     [dateexpires] DATETIME, 
     [userid] INT, 
     [title] VARCHAR(MAX), 
     [details] VARCHAR(MAX), 
     [lat] DOUBLE, 
     [lon] DOUBLE, 
     [radius] INT, 
     [imageid] INT);
```

Comment: [What represents a double in sql server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209181/what-represents-a-double-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 8):

Double isn't a SQL Server datatype.

This should be a complete list of all the data types, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx).

I should note, you'll probably want to use FLOAT or DECIMAL to solve your problem, but I don't know anything about the rest of what you're doing (producers or consumers), so I'll let you pick which data type will solve your problem.

Comment: It worked, Thanks, I was using the same syntax as MySQL which uses DOUBLE as a data type.

Answer (score 6):

Change DOUBLE to FLOAT to fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use decimal(9,2) or the precision you require rather than DOUBLE

Answer (score 1):

You simply needed to remove DOUBLE, as it's not a supported data type. I'd also reccomend organizing your query in a more easy to read manner such as:

```
CREATE TABLE alertitem (
    [id] INT,
    [dateposted] DATETIME,
    [daterevised] DATETIME,
    [datestart] DATETIME,
    [dateexpires] DATETIME,
    [userid] INT,
    [title] VARCHAR(MAX),
    [details] VARCHAR(MAX),
    [lat] FLOAT,
    [lon] FLOAT,
    [radius] INT,
    [imageid] INT);
```

You'll find it easier to troubleshoot bugs this way.