# Expecting ID Error - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem when i create a table in SQL Server

once i chose DOUBLE as the data type, the error jumped on my face !!!

THIS is the following code :

```
CREATE TABLE BATCH 
( Product_Name  VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
  Product_Brand VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT Price_FK FOREIGN KEY (Product_Name,Product_Brand)REFERENCES Product   (Product_Name,Product_Brand),
  BATCH_Date AS GETDATE(),
  BATCH_OriginalPrice DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  BATCH_TAX DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  BATCH_ProductCost DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
)
```

The error is like this after each double 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NOT'

and when i pass the mouse over it, it says 
" Incorrect syntax near 'NOT'. Expecting ID "

Can someone tell me what's the problem !!!

Answer (score 11):

`double` isn't a data type in SQL, you'll have to use `float` or `real`.

With your example you could use `money` as well.

related: [What represents a double in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209181/what-represents-a-double-in-sql-server)

Comment: Complete list of SQL Server [data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx)

Comment: But how would i map it in java ? What does represent the [MONEY] in java ?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `DOUBLE` in SQL SERVER. Try using Decimal or Float or Real or Money or even Smallmoney. See [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258271%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

```
CREATE TABLE BATCH 
( Product_Name  VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
  Product_Brand VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT Price_FK FOREIGN KEY (Product_Name,Product_Brand)REFERENCES Product (Product_Name,Product_Brand),
  BATCH_Date AS GETDATE(),
  BATCH_OriginalPrice REAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  BATCH_TAX REAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  BATCH_ProductCost REAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `DECIMAL`, `FLOAT` or `REAL` datatypes -

```
CREATE TABLE BATCH ( 
    Product_Name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
    Product_Brand VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    BATCH_OriginalPrice DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    BATCH_TAX DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    BATCH_ProductCost DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 , 
    BATCH_Date AS GETDATE(), 
    CONSTRAINT Price_FK FOREIGN KEY (Product_Name,Product_Brand)
    REFERENCES Product (Product_Name,Product_Brand)
)
```

Comment: But how would i represent the these data type in JAVA ?