# Nhibernate float issue with sql float in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, nhibernate, floating-point

I have a nullable float column in a sql table which is mapped in Nhibernate. The property for this table class is defined:

```
public virtual float? floatColumn { get; set; }
```

I have another class which has

```
public float? anotherFloatPrprty { get; set; }
```

I get this error

> The type System.Double can not be assigned to a property of type System.Nullable`1[System.Single] setter of MyProject

with the following session query

```
var j = session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT floatColumn As anotherFloatPrprty from myTable")
```

So I changed the table to have that column as not null, But I still get the following error.

> {"Object of type 'System.Double' cannot be converted to type 'System.Single'."}

Obviously when I don't have any value in floatColumn, I don't get any exceptions, but as soon as some values are inserted to the table (ranging from 0.01 to 1), I get these exceptions.

How do I map nullable float correctly in Nhibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the **SQL** *keyword* `float` and **C#** *keyword* `float` are confusing. Because they do not match.

As stated in documentation: [SqlDbType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx#Mtps_DropDownFilterText)

```
Member name    Description
...            ...
Float          Double. A floating point number within 
                 the range of -1.79E +308 through 1.79E +308.
```

Also check:

- [What represents a double in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1209181/1679310)
- [SQL Server 2008 R2 - float and real (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

**Summary**: use the `double`

```
public virtual double? floatColumn { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you Radim. I've read a lot of documents on this issue. Seems like I have no other option than changing the sql column to double.

Comment: Do you mean changing the C# mapping? to double? That makes sense to me. Really. I would say this should not be an iseue, right? Anyhow. Good luck with NHibenrate. Great tool ;)

Comment: Yes Radim. I changed the mapping to double, and it worked. Although I am not sure if I should change the sql table to double. At the moment I haven't changed it

Comment: Good to see, that it is working. The precision on the SQL server side is mostly dependent on your Business needs, rights. If this column contains percentage... float(24) would be ok. Also, the *double* takes twice as much space as *single*. But these are "tunings" which you still can adjust later. Now, the connectivity via NHibernate is working... that's great ;)