# Using CAST and bigint

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to understand what does this statement does

```
SUM(CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS bigint) * 8192.)/1024 /1024
```

Also why is there a dot after 8192? Can anybody explain this query bit by bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FILEPROPERTY()` returns an `int` value. Note that the `SpaceUsed` property is not in bytes but in "pages" - [and in SQL Server a page is 8KiB](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969(v=sql.105).aspx), so multiplying by `8192` to get the size in KiB is appropriate.

I've never encountered a trailing dot without fractional digits before - [the documentation for constants/literals in T-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx) does not give an example of this usage, but reading it implies it's a `decimal`:

> `decimal` constants are represented by a string of numbers that are not enclosed in quotation marks and contain a decimal point.

Thus multiplying the `bigint` value by a `decimal` would yield a `decimal` value, which may be desirable if you want to preserve fractional digits when dividing by `1024` (and then `1024` again), though it's odd that those numbers are actually `int` literals, so the operation would just be truncation-division.

I haven't tested it, but you could try just this:

```
SELECT
    SUM( FILEPROPERTY( name, 'SpaceUsed' ) ) * ( 8192.0 / 10485760 ) AS TotalGigabytes
FROM
    ...
```

If you're reading through code and you need to do research to understand what it's doing - do a favour for the next person who reads the code by adding an explanatory comment to save them from having to do research, e.g. "gets the total number of 8KiB pages used by all databases, then converts it to gigabytes".

Answer (score 2):

The dot `.` after an Integer converts it implicitly to decimal value. This is most likely here to force the output to also be decimal (not an integer). In this case you only need one part of the operation to be  converted to force the output to be in that type.

This probably has to do with bytes/pages since the numbers `8192` and `1024` (most likely for converting to larger unit). One could also imply this by the value of property which indicates how much space is being used by a file.

A page fits within 8kB which means that multiplying pages value by `8192` does convert the output to bytes being used. Then division two times by `1024` succesfully converts the output to gigabytes.

---

Explanation on functions used:

- [`FILEPROPERTY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188401.aspx) returns a value for a file name which is stored within database. If a file is not present, null value is returned
- `CAST` is for casting the value to type bigint
- `SUM` is an aggregate function used in a query to sum values for a specified group

Comment: SQL Server does not have a `double` type. The dot is for `decimal` values which are not IEEE-754 floating numbers (so it is incorrect to refer to that type as "`double`").

Comment: @Dai thanks for your comment. I didn't mention `double` datatype. I'm only mentioning double precision values. Isn't it correct, that a `decimal` datatype consists of precision and scale?

Comment: No, the `decimal` type stores individual decimal digits (hence the name), it is a different internal representation to IEEE-754 ("`float`" or "`single`") - which means it can store exact decimal vales, whereas IEEE-754 stores approximate values: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209181/what-represents-a-double-in-sql-server

Comment: Thanks so much Kamil for the detailed explanation. Upvoted.